# WYGWAM freezes on Chrome when popping up a dialog box

Tags: wygwam

When clicking the Link tool, or from the Link tool, clicking "Browse Server," or Create table, or Add Image, WYGWAM freezes for somewhere between 0-60 seconds. This just happens on the first clicks; subsequent clicks work fine.

This only happens on Chrome; FireFox is OK.

It's also only happening on EE 5.3.0 / WYGWAM 5.0.3; my EE2 site is working fine.

Any ideas on what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar recently, it "appeared" to be lack of server memory/RAM - our server guy bumped that up and all was fine after that. Can't say that's the cause of your problem but worth a shot.

Comment: Interesting--the server CPU is being hit pretty hard just by having a new entry open / typing into WYGWAM. The "sedispatch" (running SELinux) is the process that's doing it. We're experimenting with adding another CPU to the server. But it's weird that so much CPU is being hit by just having a new entry open and typing into WYGWAM.

Answer (score 0):

It ends up the server CPU was being pegged when a new entry was opened (maybe autosave?). Increasing CPUs (from 1 CPU to 1 CPU + 4 cores) solved this. sedispatch was hitting 20% CPU, and now it's < 1%. I don't know if that is directly related, but it's associated to some degree.

Comment: Glad you sorted it! Modern CMS's it seems are needing more server resources to run.